# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.formats.csvs'

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to create a simple csv:

```
    dataframe.to_csv(
        psv_file_name, encoding='utf-8', header=True, sep="|",
        doublequote=True, quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL, index=False
    )
```

and I'm having this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas.io.formats.csvs'
```

Last week was working fine. Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: did you update your pandas

Comment: Not that I know, but I'm not the only one using the server, so maybe. It's in 0.24.2

Comment: @CBury Have you tried deleting and recreating your environment (or whatever equivalent you’re using) ?

Comment: No, I don't have permission to do that. Do you think it is not possible to solve by code?

Answer (score 6):

Try to install/re-install pandas again. For me conda install pandas and run my code again worked.